# Communicate with a regulator via serial port with Local Process Bus (LPB) protocol

Tags: c#, serial-port, protocols, bus

My goal is to retrieve data and control my boiler. This boiler communicates with my controller via a digital bus (LPB) which was developed by SIEMENS. I did not find a complete document on the protocol because it is a closed protocol.

My controller is a RVL-480 which allows to do temperature control and other things.
I would like to make the communication with a C# program that will send requests on the serial port where the controller is connected.
If you have already worked on this protocol or this equipment and you have information about the frames I am interested.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if following helps : https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/937/1085937/att_904/v1/6ES5_998-0UF23.pdf?force_isolation=true

Comment: You may want to contact company.  These days the protocols are not closed.  Start here : https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/products?mfn=ps&pnid=18780&lc=en-US

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I could not found this doc. I just sent a support request, I hope it is not closed as you said :)

Comment: Try this page : https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/78028908/cpu-cpu-communication-with-simatic-controllers?dti=0&lc=en-US

Comment: Ok what is it ?

Comment: I think it is the technical manual with the command formats.

Comment: Ok I found a lot of information about the LPB/BSB communication including a german forum who were looking for a way to communicate on a RS232 port. It would be necessary to convert the signal coming from the lpb to be able to read it on a RS232 port. The software part is still unclear for sending read/write requests with the address and segment number and I did not find anything in the documents you sent me. I am interested if people have already looked into this.

Comment: Is it just a voltage level conversion?  A lot of people these days are sending RS-232 at 5V (or even lower) which the RS-232 specification is +/-12V.   Sending from 5V to 12V receivers isn't an issue.  Going the other way could cause damage.  There are converters available to do this conversion.

Comment: If it is just voltage I have a ten dollar solution.  Adafruit make a USB to serial cable (954) where the USB side looks like a RS-232 serial port inside the PC.  The other end of cable is 5V serial with square posts.  Product 18 has a 9 pin serial connector.  See : https://www.adafruit.com/category/33

Comment: Ok so my friend make the convertor and now i get this in serial port data received :
`81 3F 01 81 FC FF 07 81 FF 19 19 61 01 19 79 01 01 01 9F 67 F9 03 87 00 61 FF 1E 01`

Comment: Not sure what manual to use.  Looks like messages start with 81 and ends with 01.  So receive data looks like three messages.

Comment: I have multiples messages start with 81 and same structure at regular interval. I have calculated the CRC but there is no correspondence with the end of the frames. Why did you say it looks like three messages ?

Comment: Only because there are three 81 in message.

Comment: So I try to read data with this [project](https://github.com/henkosch/lpb-serial-dotnet) I have the following result : `Destination: ALL, Source: 41, Type: INF, Command: 0500006b`

Comment: So source (41 hex) correspond well to the address and segment number of my regulator.

Comment: The code is not documented very well.  I'm looking at the Protocol folder, the file ValueType.cs.  There looks like there 79 different types but not sure which bytes in the receive data are the value type.  You are getting a type INF.  Not sure where this is coming from.

Comment: Here all commands received :
Dst: f2, Src: 2e, Type: INF, Command: 291901f4
Dst: ALL, Src: 2e, Type: INF, Command: 0500006b
Dst: ALL, Src: 2e, Type: INF, Command: 05000068
Dst: ALL, Src: 2e, Type: INF, Command: 05000066
Dst: ALL, Src: 2e, Type: INF, Command: 2d000231

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243069/discussion-between-neuromob-and-jdweng).